# Is my ajax call correct?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I am trying to make a simple call like this in `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url :"${info.contextPath}/secured/contribution/employer/contributionsearch/viewNewContribution?employerCode="+code+"&contbYear="+year+"&contbMonth="+month
            +"&orgId="+orgId+"&contbStatus="+status+"&employerDetailId="+employerId,
    success: function(data){
        alert('123'+data);
        $("#newContribution").html(data);
    }
});
```

However, when I see the pop up of my `alert` I only see '123'. Is my call wrong ?

Comment: What should you be getting?

Comment: It really depends on what `viewNewContribution` is sending in response

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `data: {key: value}` instead of url concatenation.
2. Make sure that server's response is correct

Answer (score 1):

Check for the server's response. If possible follow this approach :

```
    $.ajax( {
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/uri',
        data : {key1 : "value1", key2 : "value2"}
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to serialize the response in alert.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url :"${info.contextPath}/secured/contribution/employer/contributionsearch/viewNewContribution?employerCode="+code+"&contbYear="+year+"&contbMonth="+month            +"&orgId="+orgId+"&contbStatus="+status+"&employerDetailId="+employerId,
    success: function(data){
        var resp = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert('123'+resp);
        $("#newContribution").html(resp);
    }
});
```